# DataTable is not populated with textbox values passing as new columns in the table

Tags: jquery, datatable, angular-datatables

DataTable is not populated with textbox values passing as new columns in the table. Have requirement like API is giving few columns and I need add few columns based on the textbox values available on the screen.
Below code I tried, table is populated but I'm not getting the data in the new columns in table. Could you pleas suggest me the issue.

```
let test1 = (document.getElementById("idtest1") as HTMLInputElement).value;
   let test2 =(document.getElementById("idtest2") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: "full_numbers",
      pageLength: 10,
      scrollCollapse: true,
      processing: true,
      destroy: true,
      scrollY:'50vh',
      columns: [
        { data: "index" },
        { data: "firstname" },
        { data: "lastname" },
        {data: null, defaultContent: test1},
        {data: null, defaultContent: test2},
      ],
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-3c2rum?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Your `ngOnInit` function only runs at the start of the program. At this point in time, the input fields are empty. The table therefore reflects this initial state, even if the user enters data into these fields.

You can see this for yourself by adding some default text to the input fields:

```
<input type="text" id="idtest1" value="initial test text">
```

Now, you will see "initial test text" in the DataTable.

And you will continue to see it even if the user changes the value, or completely removes it.

You need to move that functionality to a `click` event attached to the "Click to load table" button.